# CVXOPT quadratic programming mean variance example

Tags: mean-variance

Trying to learn how to use CVXOPT to do quant finance optimization.

For the example given on page https://cvxopt.org/userguide/coneprog.html#quadratic-programming . I feel confused how this "S" matrix is defined. From the doc, it should solve the problem as shown :
[image: below]

This gives correlation matrix as

0.2 0.3 -0.4 0

0.3 0.1 0 0

-0.4 0 0.05 0

0 0 0 0
which is not even close to the "S" matrix given

```
S = matrix([[ 4e-2,  6e-3, -4e-3,    0.0 ],
        [ 6e-3,  1e-2,  0.0,     0.0 ],
        [-4e-3,  0.0,   2.5e-3,  0.0 ],
        [ 0.0,   0.0,   0.0,     0.0 ]])
```

Can you kindly explain it a bit?

Also, what's the reason to calculate the risk aversion parameter 'mu' as:

```
mus = [ 10**(5.0*t/N-1.0) for t in range(N) ]
```

Thanks

Comment: Look at the diagonal: 4e-2 is the square of 0.2, 1e-2 is the square of 0.1, 2.5e-3 is the square of 0.05, and 0 is the square of 0. So these are variances instead of standard deviations. The off-diagonals are covariances (which are products of a correlation and two standard deviations, example 6e-3 is 0.2*0.1*0.30).

Comment: Hi, thank you so much! I realized it's covariance matrix instead of correlation matrix. Thanks a lot for point out! Do you know why 'mus' is calculated in such a way above? It seems it's a exponential mesh instead of a regular one. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is an exponential mesh. Probably to generate a big range of cases, some very small values and some large ones. Not sure I know anything more.

Comment: Thanks again for the comments. Really appreciated.

Comment: Also check out: https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxportfolio